# tkinter basic queries with python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to tkinter

```
import datetime as dt
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


dt1 = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y""%m""%d")
time1 = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')

msg1= dt1+" "+time1+ " Test Message XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
master = Tk()
top = Tk()
top.geometry("100x100")
messagebox.showinfo("information", msg1)
top.mainloop()
```

I have basically 3 issues in this basic code

1. It is creating additional blank windows along with my message which is not required. How to avoid this ?
2. I want to display my message into single line how can i do this ?
3. How to change font and color of this message ?

Comment: 1. Delete the line `master=Tk()`. 2. Your message is already a single line. 3. You can't, at least not with `messagebox`. You need to create your own `Toplevel` window.

Comment: after removing master=Tk() still showing one blank window

Comment: There will always be a root window, and your messagebox is a popup from the root window. If you want to hide it, you can call `top.withdraw()` after `top=Tk()`.

Comment: ok thanks, blank window issue is resolved. Can I change message text and color in this or as mentioned by Henry I have to look for Toplevel window only ?

Comment: You will have to make your own by `Toplevel()`. It should be easy enough - just a couple lines involving a `Label`, a `Button` and some popup sound.

Comment: import tkinter as tk
master = tk.Tk()
whatever_you_do = "Whatever you do will be insignificant, but it is very important that you do it.\n(Mahatma Gandhi)"
msg = tk.Message(master, text = whatever_you_do)
msg.config(bg='lightgreen', font=('times', 24, 'italic'))
msg.pack()
tk.mainloop()

Comment: Can this text message can be displayed in a one line ? I get this example from https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_message_widget.php

Comment: Remove the `\n` in your message.

Comment: Removed \n but still not able to display message in one line. It is showing some window and message is getting wrapped.